# В любом случае(,) что тебе надо от меня?

Tags: запятые

Нужна запятая?

`В любом случае(,) что тебе надо от меня?`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Запятая ставится:

***В любом случае**, // что тебе надо от меня?*

1. Очевидно, что словосочетание **не вписывается** в основную структуру данного предложения и поэтому   (в этом предложении) **обособляется** в обязательном порядке.

По тематике его можно отнести к вводным словам **с ОЦЕНОЧНЫМ значением,** как и сочетание [***во всяком случае.***](http://new.gramota.ru/spravka/punctum?layout=item&id=58_293)  Обособление обоих сочетаний  факультативное и определяется путем грамматического анализа, как и для всех парных вариантов наречие/вводное слово.

Тире вместо запятой возможно,  **но совсем необязательно.**

2. **Но правила** не позволяют его считать вводным словом. **Нельзя!** И все дружно **повторяют**: "Д*а, да, нельзя, ни в коем случае*!"
3. Только вот современные писатели **так не считают** (примеры из Нацкорпуса):

*Скажем так, я подумаю. **В любом случае**, не сегодня. — Ок, когда скажешь.*

***В любом случае,** стволов за двести информатор ручается.*

***В любом случае**, у тебя будут все шансы туда врасти.*

***В любом случае**, ко мне это никакого отношения не имеет.*

***В любом случае**, ты не совсем такой, как остальные.*

**Примечание**

(1) Сколько уже изучаем вводные слова, но никак не можем понять **простую истину**. Наречное выражение без особого труда  становится **вводным** сочетанием, если это **авторская оценка** ситуации.

(2) При этом функция вводного слова или наречия во многом зависит от **структуры** предложения. **Интонация** вариантов также различна.

(3) Слово часто используется в речи. Иногда структура предложения такова, что возможность обособления или  необособления просматривается **однозначно**. Но бывает и так, что по структуре возможны **оба варианта**. И тогда приходится решать, что лучше: обозначить **объективность** ситуации  или авторское **субъективное** (оценочное) мнение.

Comment: Не поняла Вас, *Sharon*. Сначала Вы пишете, что *запятая ставится* (то есть обособление нужно). Потом Вы делаете странный вывод: *обособление **факультативное.*** А это означает, что запятую можно не ставить. Так какое же решение из двух — правильное?

Comment: Здесь обособляется однозначно, да вы и сами поставили тире.  Не обособить просто невозможно. Я исправила ответ (сначала не туда написала про факультативность). Спасибо за замечание.

Comment: Sharon, я согласен с вашим ответом, только вот про факультативность всё же непонятно. Вы говорите, что сначала не туда написали, но оно там и осталось, где пишете о вводном.

Comment: Я исправила. Там я пишу об общем правиле обособления парных вариантов вводное слово/наречие.

Comment: Отлич-чный ответ, плюс от меня.

Answer (score 2):

> [В ЛЮБОМ СЛУЧАЕ](http://new.gramota.ru/spravka/punctum?layout=item&id=58_285), *наречное выражение*
> Не требует постановки знаков препинания.
> ***В любом случае** ты знаешь, как себя вести.* А. Вампилов, Прощание в июне. *Но его расчеты не проверены, и **в любом случае** это дело будущего.* В. Пелевин, Generation «П».

***В любом случае*** в предложении отвечает на вопросы "когда?", "в каком случае?" и выполняет роль обстоятельства. Оно может быть заменено на синонимичные выражения при *любых обстоятельствах, несмотря ни на что, при любых условиях, всё равно.*

***В любом случае, в крайнем случае, в нашем случае*** — это такие выражения, после которых очень хочется поставить запятую. Но она не нужна.

■ В нашем предложении вместо предполагаемой запятой я бы поставила **тире**, чтобы обозначить паузу при пропуске подразумеваемого сказуемого *скажи* (или *объясни, повтори, растолкуй*...) и чтобы разделить повествовательную и вопросительную часть предложения.

***В любом случае — что тебе надо от меня?***

Из Нацкорпуса:
*В любом случае — что общего у меня может быть с девушкой, которая с кулинарки?* (А. Слаповский. Хроника № 13).